# My delete query is not working in supabase

Tags: reactjs, postgresql, bucket, supabase, supabase-database

```
async function deleteImage(imageName) {
        const { data, error } = await supabase
          .storage
          .from('img')
          .remove([ CDNURL + "/" + imageName ])
console.log(data)
```

This is my code. My delete query is not working.

'img' is my bucket name and 'denim' is my folder in the bucket where the images are stored.

Comment: Welcome in StackOverflow, what do you mean by "not working" ? what's not working ? do you have logs ?

Comment: Can you output the error message using console.log?

Comment: I am not getting any errors . If I print the data it prints an empty array like this '[ ]'.

Comment: The query is not working

Answer (score 0):

async function deleteImage(imageName) {
const { data, error } = await supabase
.storage
.from('img/denim')
.remove([ CDNURL + "/" + imageName ])
console.log(data)

Comment: it shows resource not found when I use like this(img/denim).

Comment: Thanks for ur reply I found the solution